# firebase api requests on react native not working

Tags: javascript, react-native-ios

I am using firebase for my app, whenever i click the logout button i get ('evaluating 'this.firebase.unauth'). What is wrong with my api request?

```js
logout() {
    this.firebase.unauth();
  }
  //this is the api request
  
  
  
  onPress() {
  Actions.logout();
  }
  //this is the action method.
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using `import firebase from 'firebase';` ? In that case you dont need `this`, just `firebase.unauth();` should do it. However, is there really a method called `unauth()` ? The docs refer to using:

```
firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
  // Sign-out successful.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

Comment: Feel free to edit your question if you have relevant code that could further detail the question.